# Able to download only 4 MB file in Selenium Python | Chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, file, csv, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing strange problem working with selenium in Python. I am downloading `.csv` file in chrome-driver using selenium in Python. But it works file when file size is below 4 MB or it has less than 10000 rows in `.csv`. Currently it downloads max 4MB file or 10000 rows in `.csv` not actual .csv file. I have checked that there is no problem in Apache2 when the script runs.

Anyone has idea how to solve it? below is my script initialization.

```
download_url = "/var/www/html/all_in_one_csv"
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
      "download.default_directory": download_url,
      "download.prompt_for_download": False,
      "download.directory_upgrade": True,
      "safebrowsing.enabled": True 
    })

    options.add_argument("download.default_directory = /usr/local/bin")
    options.add_argument('--headless')
    options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage') 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'/var/www/html/chromedriver')

    driver.command_executor._commands["send_command"] = ("POST", '/session/$sessionId/chromium/send_command')
    params = {'cmd': 'Page.setDownloadBehavior', 'params': {'behavior': 'allow', 'downloadPath': download_url}}
    command_result = driver.execute("send_command", params)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I just increased the sleep timing `time.sleep(3)` to `time.sleep(120)` after the Download button clicking because it will take time to download the large file.